# Active Directory User log in to SP! after he register his cv , i only want him to view it not other users how to solve this?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have two users 1 Aministrator and 1 Guest.
I have created a formula there u can fil in your "CV" after pressing register the information that the user has fillt in should be displayed in a Gridview. My problem is now that i dont want guest for example to se the administrators CV. how do i solve this? should i upload the webpart that displays the "Cv" On My Personal Site because i want the Cv do be private for every user that uploads the cv?

Comment: How are the cv saved, as documents in a document library or something else?

Comment: Thats the best bet for you. as it will be their personal page and no one else is able to see that except SP Farm admin.